# How I can interpret the attached tree?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, machine-learning-model

Is the total sample size = 30.891 and the overall percentage of “yes” = 11,3%? How I can describe the leaves predicting "yes" outcome in term of explicative variables and values?
What are the variables appearing in the second tree level?
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you understand decision trees?

Comment: Check them out http://forums.fast.ai/t/another-treat-early-access-to-intro-to-machine-learning-videos/6826/10?u=ecdrid

Answer (score 1):

Initially in the uppermost node, you have 30 samples or data points that needs to be classified into yes/no category. Out of 30, nearly 27 are with no label and 3 are with yes label.

In the next level, it gets divided on the basis of poutcome value. Records in left side of the tree at level 2 are one with poutcome value is **non-existent or fail** while that on right hand side are with value **success**.